# "This question may have an answer here:" banner for the Author

Tags: support, exact-duplicates, close-reasons, banners

The duplicated question flag has been correctly raised for my [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2837733/431789). There is a banner on my page asking for some action on my part.

How do I respond?

The banner offers me two inappropriate choices that are not universally exhaustive.

- "That solved my problem" button
  The duplicated question has some excellent answers but none are complete.
- "No, my question is different"
  The spirit of the questions are identical, if worded differently.

Additionally, it would be a shame to lose the high quality answer from @GottfriedHelms. It offers a different, striking visualization of the problem. If this weren't the case, I would immediately vote to close my question.

How should I proceed?

Comment: It is likely that the question can be merged to the original (duplicated) question; in this way, the answer(s) you received will be included among those in the original.  Of course, however, we can only merge a post already closed as a dupe, with the duplicated target. So closing as a dupe may be appropriate.  If or when that happens, be sure to flag a mod (click on: needs moderator attention, and explain the situation, requesting a merge).

Answer (score 4):

You say that the duplicate flag was raised *correctly.* If you agree it is a duplicate, which it seems is the case from this phrasing, you should select "yes" if you disagree that it is a duplicate you should select "no." (If you are unsure then just don't reply.)

Either way the answer is not lost, a question closed as a duplicate is still around. If it has an answer there is not even an auto-forward. What's more, it will be even linked back on the target.

In addition, as amWhy pointed out, in some cases we can consider merging posts. In this cases the answer would end up on the target.

Comment: "Yes" $\not \equiv$ "That solved my problem"